# How to remove unused global css classes from individual pages in nuxt.js

Tags: css, performance, webpack, nuxt.js, tailwind-css

Nuxt works great in performance perspective ,  but i want to remove unused css from the individual pages

**My Use Case**

I'm using nuxt js with tailwind ( jit mode enabled ). So with `jit` i'm getting only used css as **jit mode remove all unnecessary css** .
But when visiting home page , let say `/` route , nuxt also load tailwind util classes which are not used in that specific page ( let say some classes defined in `other` page )
, i know this is because tailwind added to global `css` property in `nuxt.config.js`

so what i want is to remove all tailwind classes which are not used in a particular page

What i tried so far

1. `Purge css` , but it removes unused classes from whole application ( rather than individual page )
2. `extractCss` , it just extract the same css in **external files**

So my question is , is there any way with which we can remove every single unused css class ( whether it's in `style` tag or global `css` ) from every page separately ?

i'm using `webpack`

Comment: Tailwind is mainly aimed to be "global" actually and then, referencing those values. Having a purge per component would be difficult to do IMO. Also, I'm pretty sure there will be no difference performance-wise at the end too. It may even be even worse if it was per component because of network latency/other factors.

Comment: @jibrail_ Isn't the build process anyway outputting only one css file for the entire project

Comment: @kissu yes i know it meant to be global , but in my case  it's a really big project with a complete UI library and a lot of pages , so for example , on index page only 10 components are used , but css classes of other 40 components are also being loaded :(

Comment: @ShayaUlman yes , but it also contain unused css clasees

Comment: How big is your Tailwind CSS bundle size?

Comment: Though it's not very big , ~5-10kb but due to the application size , we want to even optimize it as much as we can , that's why it's concerning to remove unused classes , because when more pages will be created , more util classes will be used and size go on increase

Comment: Not sure that optimizing as much is useful. Especially, I'm not sure that serving CSS each time is the best way to go here, since 5~10kb of initial rendering is totally fine and there is probably a drawback of doing so (repaint, CSSOM, network?). There will be a lot of other performance issues that could be improved before this too (on the JS part). Still, you can probably try [this thing](https://twitter.com/nuxt_js/status/1072799110007283712).